# Junit test for listview drag and drop

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, junit

How to do Junit testing with Android custom listview drag and drop. I am using beaurca drag sort library for my custom listview, its working fine. I have tested onitem click with JUnit and want to test drag sort function too, but not able to do so. Do anyone previously has executed a test case on drag sort on listview, please help me.

Below is the snapshot of my problem,

```
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    getListActivity = getActivity();
    dragSortListView = (DragSortListView) atosListActivity
            .findViewById(com.as.listreq.R.id.item_list);
    listAdapter = dragSortListView.getAdapter();
}

public void testEntryConditions() {

    sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    assertTrue(dragSortListView.getOnItemClickListener() != null);
    assertTrue(listAdapter != null);
    assertEquals(listAdapter.getCount(), ADAPTER_COUNT);        
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
}


public void testDragAndDrop() { //not completed 

    sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    // event time MUST be retrieved only by this way!
    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();    
    getListActivity .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            View listItemView = null;                               
            listItemView = dragSortListView.getAdapter().getView(2, null, dragSortListView);
            MotionEvent event1 = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 200, 200, 0);
            // MotionEvent e1 = null;               
            DragSortController dsc = new DragSortController(dragSortListView);
            dsc.onCreateFloatView(2);
            dsc.startDrag(2, 200, 200);
            dsc.onTouch(listItemView, event1);
        }
    });     
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME);          
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of your test - what do you want to test after drag and drop? As well - what are for all these sleep sections?

Comment: I want to test if drag and drop features are working fine, in my listview. Sleep functions are there to pause test functions for 3-4 sec after executing another test function, so that I can see if the test cases are working as per my given conditions.